# Access to SelectedPath in Form2

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two form, `FolderBrowserDialog` in Form1 and I want to use `SelectedPath`  in Form 2.
I don't know why but when I click on Form1 Button to show Form2 ,This Error will be appear :

> Invalid URI: The URI is empty

I set Form Control Modifiers: Public and FolderBrowseDialog Seletedpath not be transferred to Form2

**Form 1 :**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   FolderBrowserDialog MyFolderBrowse = new FolderBrowserDialog();
   if(MyFolderBrowse.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
   {
      txtpath.Text = MyFolderBrowse.SelectedPath;
   }
}

private void Showfrm2Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Form2 Frm2 = new Form2();
  Frm2.ShowDialog();
}
```

**Form 2 :**

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Form1 Frm1 = new Form1();
   webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(Frm1.txtpath.Text);
}
```

any solution...?

Comment: I don't think you are showing all of the code involved, because `string Form1SelectedPath = Frm.myFolderBrowseDialog.SelectedPath;` does not compile with the code provided.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

The problem is, if I understand it correctly from the code you post it, is that you create a new instance of `Form2` and then in the `Load`event of the `Form2` you create a new instance of `Form1` and the information you need is the instance of `Form1` you already have.

You already have an instance of `Form1`. I would do it by two one of the 2 options:

1. Create a public property in `Form2` and assign it when creating the `Form2` instance

   ```
   public class Form2: Form 
   {
       //{...}
       public string SelectedPath { get; set;}
       //{...}
       private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {       
            webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(this.SelectedPath);
        }
   }

   private void Showfrm2Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      Form2 Frm2 = new Form2();
      Frm2.SelectedPath = txtpath.Text;
      Frm2.ShowDialog();
   }
   ```
2. Create an argument in the `Form2` constructor and pass the selected path from `Form1`

   ```
   public class Form2: Form 
   {
       //{...}
       private string _selectedPath;
       public Form2(string selectedPath) 
       { 
           _selectedPath = selectedPath;
       }
       //{...}
       private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {       
          webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(_selectedPath);
       }
   }


   private void Showfrm2Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      Form2 Frm2 = new Form2(txtpath.Text);
      Frm2.ShowDialog();
   }
   ```